# Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client, what to do?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, charset, easyphp-devserver

How to solve this? For the record, I do not have access to my.ini file so that option I cannot try. I am looking for other options to solve this.

I use MySQL 8.1 command client, EasyPHP Devserver and Apache 2.4 on Windows 11 to do some school work.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the
> client. Please, report to the developers in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\cfg.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown
> to the client. Please, report to the developers in C:\Program Files
> (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\cfg.php on line 11 Connection
> failed: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to
> the developers

I have html form, which should connect to insert.php but all I get is that error message and nothing more.

Comment: What's the encoding on the db?

Comment: Why don't you have access to the ini file? Is your machine locked down somehow?